# Protractor AngularJS count, copy, and verify a list span

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, html-lists, protractor

I am new to automated testing, Protractor, and angularJS.  I have a list that I would like to count, copy to an array maybe, and verify the list text is present. For example The list shows Attractions, Capacity, and Content to the user so they know what privileges they have.

Below is the .html

```html
<div class="home-info">
  <div class="home-top home-section">
    <h3>User Information</h3>
    <div class="home-box">
      <div class="property-group wide">
        <span>
                    Change Phillips<br />
                </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-box">
      <div class="property-group wide">
        <div>Editors:</div>
        <span>
                    <ul class="property-stack">
                        <li><span>Attractions</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Capacity</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Content</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Media</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Options</span>
        </li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li><span>Upload CADs</span>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Below is the code I have written.  I can get the first item on the list however using .all isn't working for me.

```js
        var text = "";
        browser.driver.findElement.all(By.xpath("//li/span")).count().then(function(count) {
          initialCount = count;
          console.log(initialCount);
        });
        browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/span")).getText().then(function(text) {
          console.log(text);
        });
```

I'm trying to avoid using xpath as I was told to try and avoid.  To be honest Im lost.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Code used for matching:

```js
        expect(myLists).toEqual(['Attractions', 'Capacity', 'Conent',
          'Media', 'Options', 'Upload CADs'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what version of protractor you're using but you should be able to just call **element** without the browser or driver prefix. Using [element.all](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all) should get you the array of of elements you're looking for.

If you want to access specific indexes within that array you can use the [.get(index)](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) suffix to the element.all

So below:

**1.** you get the array of the elements

**2.** you get the count of the array

**3.** we call a for loop to iterate through all the indexes of the array

**4.** each index of the array we call the getText() and print it to the console

```
var j = 0;  // using this since the i iterator in the for loop doesn't work within a then function
var textList = [];
var text = "";
var myLists = element.all(by.css("li span"));
myLists.count().then(function(count) {
  console.log(count);
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    myLists.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
    textList[j++] = text; 
    console.log(text);
    });
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

In researching I actually found another way to iterate through the array of elements by using the [.each()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) suffix to the element.all.

```
var j = 0;  // using this since the i iterator in the for loop doesn't work within a then function
var textList = [];
var text = "";
var myLists = element.all(by.css("li span"));
myLists.count().then(function(count) {
    console.log(count);
    myLists.each(function(element, index) {
        element.getText().then(function (text) {
        textList[j++] = text;
        console.log(index, text);
      });
    });
});
```

you should be able to use the textList array to match things.

```
   expect(textList).toEqual(['Attractions', 'Capacity', 'Conent',
      'Media', 'Options', 'Upload CADs'
    ]);
```

Comment: the page I am working with is non-angular so if I'm doing this correctly i would need browser.driver right?

Comment: I believe that might of been the case in early versions of protractor but the app I'm testing is non angular and the only real specific we've needed is to make sure you declare

browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

Comment: That did it, thanks so much.  I was ready to rip my hair out.

Comment: I attempted to match however i'm clearly doing that wrong too as I got an infinite loop error. Updating my code above. @BarretV

Comment: @NicolePhillips I updated my answers to add the text results to an array so you can compare them in the expect.